# Optimizing GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Basically I need help improving the performance of a page full of gridviews to reduce the amount of C# and move as many GridView settings into the ASP Code (not the data itself, that's bound at run time and needs to stay in the C#).

I'm relatively new to the GridView control and need help moving the settings into the GridView, as the page this code is on will have about 8 or 9 tables.

Here's my ASP code:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="tblBasicProcessingTime"
    Caption="Basic Processing Stats" ShowHeader="False">
</asp:GridView>
```

And my C# Code:

```
var longestTime = ReportData.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeSpentProcessing).FirstOrDefault();
var averageTime = ReportData.Average(x => x.TimeSpentProcessing);
var shortestTime = ReportData.OrderBy(x => x.TimeSpentProcessing).FirstOrDefault();

var table = new DataTable();

const string col1Name = "Header";
const string col2Name = "Data";

table.Columns.Add(col1Name);
table.Columns.Add(col2Name);

var row1 = table.NewRow();
row1[col1Name] = "Longest Processing Time";
row1[col2Name] = longestTime.TimeSpentProcessing;
table.Rows.Add(row1);

var row2 = table.NewRow();
row2[col1Name] = "Average Processing Time";
row2[col2Name] = averageTime;
table.Rows.Add(row2);

var row3 = table.NewRow();
row3[col1Name] = "Shortest Processing Time";
row3[col2Name] = shortestTime.TimeSpentProcessing;
table.Rows.Add(row3);

tblBasicProcessingTime.DataSource = table;
tblBasicProcessingTime.DataBind();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `<Columns>` property of GridView to define columns specification. Set `ShowHeader="True"` And bind only 1 row to GridView.

Comment: If I add columns manually to the ASP code, and then try and bind data to them in C#, it refuses saying the column the data is being bound to doesn't exist. How would I fix that?

Comment: If you've specified, `<asp:BoundField DataField="LPT" HeaderText="Longest Processing Time" />`, then your `DataTable table` object must be having `LPT` column in it. Then it won't give error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView
            ID="gvList"
            runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            EnableModelValidation="True"
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            Width="100%"
            RowStyle-Height="25px"
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="ui-th-div-ie"
            RowStyle-CssClass="TR_ROW1"
            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="TR_ROW2"
            HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#0073ea"
            BorderWidth="1px"
            CellPadding="2"
            HorizontalAlign="Center"
            OnPageIndexChanging="gvList_PageIndexChanging"
            AllowPaging="true"
            AllowSorting="true"
            PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
            PageSize="1"
            OnSorting="gvList_Sorting">

            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="20%" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: CommonResources, lbl_InstoreHistLotNo.Text %>" SortExpression="LotNo">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_InstoreHistLotNo" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LotNo")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: CommonResources, lbl_InstoreHistPartNo.Text %>" SortExpression="PartCode">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_InstoreHistPartNo" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PartCode")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: CommonResources, lbl_InstoreHistPartName.Text %>" SortExpression="PartName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_InstoreHistPartName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PartName")%>'/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: CommonResources, lbl_InstoreHistInQuality.Text %>" SortExpression="Quality">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_InstoreHistInQuality" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Quality")%>'/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: CommonResources, lbl_InstoreHistInUsercode.Text %>" SortExpression="UserCode">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_InstoreHistInUsercode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserCode")%>'/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="15%" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: CommonResources, lbl_InstoreHistInTime.Text %>" SortExpression="InStoreDate">
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"   />
            <PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" Mode="Numeric" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

This is just a simple demo for gridview databind.
However, my header text is loading from resource file, you can set by yourself, like string "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"

In the back end , your code may like this:

```
DataTable dt = SqlHelper.ExcuteDataSet("select * from InStoreHistory");
gvList.DataSource = dt;
gvList.DataBind();
```